# how to use the value of a cell as variable that has been previously stored

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my problem:

I have a cell, let´s say I1, with the property value equals to `Monday`.

Previously i have stored `Monday=` as a sum of a range.

I would need to reference the cell I1 and get the sum in order to compare the result with an if statement.

I need the macro to fill a certain number of "1s" depending on the restriction for each day of the week if `Cells(2, i).Offset(-1, 0).Value < 2 Then`

```
Sub dayweek()

    Dim i As Byte, Monday As Byte, Tuesday As Byte, Wednesday As Byte, Thursday As Byte, Friday As Byte
    i = 9

    Monday = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(2, i + 4)))

    Tuesday = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(2, i - 1), Cells(2, i + 3)))

    Wednesday = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(2, i - 2), Cells(2, i + 2)))

    Thursday = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(2, i - 3), Cells(2, i + 1)))

    Friday = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(2, i - 4), Cells(2, i)))

    Do While i < 14
        If Cells(2, i).Offset(-1, 0).Value < 2 Then 'In this cell i have the value "monday","tuesday", etc...

            Cells(2, i).Value = 1
            i = i + 1
        Else
            Cells(2, i).Value = 0
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: You really don't seem to need what you're asking for. In fact you already know in advance both the values (i.e.: "Monday", "Tuesday"...) of the cells your variables are supposed to reference and their addresses (i.e.: "I1", "J1", ...) hence the searched _nominal_ equivalence between your variables name (again: "Monday", Tuesday"...) and the values in the cells you already know they are in, isn't useful in any way. You may want to add some more explanation about why it would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following my comment, I'd advise you to simply use an array to store the sum results and then write them in wanted cells:

```
Sub dayweek()
    Dim startColumn As Long, nColumns As Long, jCol As Long

    startColumn = 9
    nColumns = 5

    ReDim results(0 To nColumns - 1) As Long ' array storing the results

    For jCol = 0 To nColumns - 1
        results(jCol) = IIf(Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Cells(2, startColumn - jCol).Resize(, nColumns)) < 2, 1, 0)
    Next
    Cells(2, startColumn).Resize(, nColumns).Value = results
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. The resize function served me as inspiration. Anyway, do you know how to reference a variable from the value of a cell?  Eg: I have a value in cell A1 equals to var1, and i have defined var1 as for example range("b1","b4").select. How could i do an "indirect" of the cell A1 to select range("b1","b4")?

Comment: You are welcome. As for the _"how to reference a variable from the value of a cell? "_, I don't get you: you cannot set a variable to `range("b1","b4").select`, while you can assign it a value or set it to an object reference

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion on option is to name the range for each day and get its sum afterwards.

```
Option Explicit

Sub dayweek()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim Monday As Range, Tuesday As Range, Wednesday As Range, Thursday As Range, Friday As Range
    Dim Result As Double

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Set Monday = .Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(2, i + 4))

        Set Tuesday = .Range(Cells(2, i - 1), Cells(2, i + 3))

        Set Wednesday = .Range(Cells(2, i - 2), Cells(2, i + 2))

        Set Thursday = .Range(Cells(2, i - 3), Cells(2, i + 1))

        Set Friday = .Range(Cells(2, i - 4), Cells(2, i))

        Result = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Monday)

    End With

End Sub
```